# Flutter 2 upgrade dependencies failed

Tags: flutter

I everyone,
I upgrade to flutter 2 and I got this error:

```
Because geoflutterfire 2.2.1 depends on rxdart ^0.24.1 and no versions of geoflutterfire match >2.2.1 <3.0.0, geoflutterfire ^2.2.1 requires rxdart ^0.24.1.
So, because sample_app depends on both rxdart ^0.26.0 and geoflutterfire ^2.2.1, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because sample_app depends on both rxdart ^0.26.0 and geoflutterfire ^2.2.1, version solving failed.)
```

**Flutter doctor:**

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.0, on macOS 11.1 20C69 darwin-x64, locale en-IL)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    ! CocoaPods 1.9.1 out of date (1.10.0 is recommended).
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To upgrade see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
```

Answer (score 5):

**SOLVED:**

add this lines below `dev_dependencies`

```
dependency_overrides:
  plugin_platform_interface: '>=2.0.0'
  intl: '>=0.17.0'
  http: '>=0.13.0'
  quiver: '>=2.0.0'
  http_parser: '>=4.0.0'
  path_provider: '>=2.0.1'
  flutter_cache_manager: '>=2.1.1'
  rxdart: '>=0.26.0'
```

****Notice**
Don't copy past my override dependencies instead look at which error you got then override it.
Moreover, you need to follow for any updates of these plugins, and if it fixed then remove the override dependencies.

Comment: can you give the right solution for the above question? I mean, which plugin override?

Comment: which error did you get? it depends on which plugin do you have in your porject