# Flutter 2.0 upgrade, pub get failed with nonsense dependency behavior

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

The project was working like a charm that started issues after the upgrade to `flutter 2.0`. following are errors upon `pub get`.

```
[delivered] flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in delivering...     
Because every version of flutter_localizations from sdk depends on intl 0.17.0 and firebase_auth_web >=0.3.0-dev.1 <0.4.0-1.0.nullsafety.0 depends on intl ^0.16.1, flutter_localizations from sdk is incompatible with firebase_auth_web >=0.3.0-dev.1 <0.4.0-1.0.nullsafety.0.
```

```
Because firebase_auth >=0.18.4 <=0.18.4 depends on firebase_auth_web ^0.3.2+2 and firebase_auth ^0.18.4+1 depends on firebase_auth_web ^0.3.2+3, firebase_auth ^0.18.4 requires firebase_auth_web ^0.3.2+2.
Thus, flutter_localizations from SDK are incompatible with firebase_auth ^0.18.4.
So, because iDelivered depends on both flutter_localizations any from SDK and firebase_auth ^0.18.4, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because delivered depends on both flutter_localizations any from SDK and firebase_auth ^0.18.4, version solving failed.)
exit code 1
```

Here is my `pubspec.yaml` for reference:

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  google_fonts: ^1.1.1

  http: ^0.12.2
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4

  firebase_core: ^0.5.3
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.4
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.4
  firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3

  parse_server_sdk_flutter: ^2.1.0

  place_picker: ^0.9.16
  google_maps_flutter: ^1.0.6

  animations: ^1.1.2
  flutter_slidable: ^0.5.7
```

Comment: look at my solution for this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66477175/flutter-2-upgrade-dependencies-failed/66477176#66477176

Comment: Check it out: [Flutter 2 upgrade - Flutter version solving failed error](https://medium.com/@pratikbutani/flutter-2-upgrade-flutter-version-solving-failed-error-33ac1087cb6b)

Answer (score 12):

My suggestion is for a few week don't update your flutter version

To downgrade your flutter (Master channel):

```
flutter downgrade 1.22.6
```

Comment: Thank u for the guidance

Answer (score 2):

Since you upgraded to **Flutter 2.0**, the flutter sdk is the source of the `flutter_localizations`. So, you have to upgrade your firebase dependencies e.g. `firebase_auth, firebase_core` to at least version 1.0.0.

My advice is that if the packages you are using have not been upgraded to null-safety **OR** they have not been recently updated, you should just stick to the 1.22.6 stable version of flutter for now.

Comment: so how to reverse back from 2.0 to 1.23.0 etc. ? i am using vs code, and my app was working smoothly and this upgrade blew it out.

Comment: I am wondering if I can possibly switch off this null safty belt for this project?

Comment: You can run flutter downgrade on terminal

Comment: Even when you are on the latest version, you can still use non null safe dart, the problem is just the packages you are using.. some have ported to null safe while some have not and these versions depend on one another.. hence, the conflict.

Comment: what all the fuss is about this Flutter Engaged, I think this should be address instantly by  flutter

Comment: It's simple @JalalAkram The flutter team updated all their dependencies as far as I am concerned.. do you want them to update all 120k+ packages on pub.dev for you? You have to use packages that have been improved or you can even improve them and make a pull request. That being said, use the old version, it's still very much up to date and valid

Comment: one last query, how can we find about if package null safety supported or not?

Comment: Normally you would see a Null Safety sticker once you open the package on `pub.dev`. You can also check the **Versions/Changelog** tab on pub.dev

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add **dependency_overrides** to resolve this conflicts :

```
dependency_overrides:
 intl: "<0.17.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade flutter using flutter downgrade **version**

Answer (score 1):

my solution for this issue..

download both 2.0.2 flutter SDK and 1.22.6 flutter SDK. change flutter SDK project-wise.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more? Are you using fvm cli or handling this manually by yourself?

I've got a new project that I want to start with latest version but without the need to update my existing projects for the moment.

Comment: @RamithDR what is your OS? my os is mac os. I do it manually. creating .bash_alias file and set `flutternew` and `flutterold`. Then setup android studio. when I release apk, `flutternew build apk` or `flutterold build apk`

Comment: I'm on Mac too. Thank you, I will try this method.

Answer (score 0):

In my app,

1. I upgrade following three pubs to latest

```
  firebase_analytics: ^7.1.1,
  firebase_core: ^1.0.1,
  firebase_messaging: ^9.0.0
```

2. I downgrade google mobile ads SDK to 7.6.9 in IOS pod file, it works for me. https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4931